# finding and replacing parameters in href with javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's the issue:

I need to check for a parameter in the query. If it's been set, then I need to change it (harder part). If it hasn't been set, I need to set it (easy part)

I was so sure it would be an easy task, but it somehow ended up being a bit more complicated than I thought. Especially for those cases where there are multiple parameters, and the one I'm looking for is in the middle somewhere.

The parameter is "siteLanguage", and is always followed by `=xx` where `xx` represents any two characters, like `en` or `es` or whatever. So maybe regex is the answer (boy, do I suck at regex)

**No frameworks for this one, guys**, just plain ol' javascript.

Comment: Do you mean the query string?

Comment: The href of the page runing the js, or the href of links on the page?

Comment: Yeah, the query string. My bad. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just doing a quick hack like so:

```
function changeLanguage(lang) {
   if (location.search.indexOf("siteLanguage") > -1) { //siteLanguage set
      location.href = location.search.replace(/siteLanguage=[a-z][a-z]/, "siteLanguage="+lang);
   } else if (location.search == "") {
      location.href += "?siteLanguage="+lang;
   } else {
      location.href += "&siteLanguage="+lang;
   }
}
```

Actually pretty happy with a 9-liner function...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've figured out how to find all the links.

The standard format of an URL is `service://host/path?query`

I suggest to cut away the `query` (just take everything after the first `?`) and then split that at `&` (because that separates parameters).

You'll be left with an array of the form `key=value`. Split that into an associative array. Now you can work on that array. After you've made your modifications, you need to join the query again and set the `href` attribute of the link.

Comment: That sounds pretty waterproof. But a bit too complicated when only looking for _one_ parameter, and even knowing the name of it. This would be better for a general function, though, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This would check all "a href=" throughout the document appending or adjusting the language.

```
checkhrefs = function(lang){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
            if (links[i].href.indexOf("siteLanguage") == -1){
                links[i].href += "&siteLanguage="+lang;
            } else {
                links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(new RegExp("siteLanguage=[a-z][a-z]"),"siteLanguage="+lang);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hehe. No, but I do like your regex. Which might be quicker than doing indexOf + substring + replace...